# In the language of two binary operations, is there a single identity that is equivalent to both distributive laws?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let our language be $\{+,* \}$. $*$ is said to be left-distributive over $+$ iff $x * (y + z)=(x*y)+(x*z)$, and is said to be right-distributive over $+$ iff $(x+y)*z=(x*z)+(y*z)$. That raises the question, in the language of $\{+,*\}$, is there a single identity which is equivalent to the conjunction of the left and right distributive laws?

Comment: If you expand the language with a multiplicative identity $1$, then the answer is yes: $$(t*(u+v))*w=((t*u)*w)+((t*v)*w).$$ In general, I don't know. But notice that often, when several identities are merged into one, that one is cumbersome to deal with.

Comment: Likewise, an element $0$ such that $x*0=0*x=0$ would give the result, with $$(t*(u+v))+((u+v)*w)=((t*u)+(t*v))+((u*w)+(v*w)).$$